# Broken AntiforgeryToken with Microsoft MSAL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-msal, antiforgerytoken

I'm working with ASP.Net MVC and I have a problem using MSAL while authenticating a User. This is because, as we use AntiforgeryToken, when the user sign in in the page of Microsoft, the token breaks and we get an error related to the token.

My question is, is there a way to keep the token even after being redirected from Microsoft login page? Or can I recreate it?

I've search on other questions and google and found nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can save the token in your [application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore) like this:

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "user.read" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
{


// Acquire the access token.

string[] scopes = new string[]{"user.read"};
string accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);

context.Token = accessToken;
}
```

Alternatively, you can [explicitly acquire tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens) by using the acquire-token methods as described in the core MSAL library. The MSAL wrapper provides the HTTP interceptor, which will automatically acquire access tokens silently and attach them to the HTTP requests to APIs.